# Can TensorFlow RNNCell have more dimensions than 3D?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to use `tf.nn.rnn` with 5D tensors of video frames (samples, time, height, width, channels) without having to flatten and reshape on each `cell.__call__`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of TensorFlow 1.2 this will be supported. It's also possible already by setting `time_major=True` and reordering the dims accordingly outside of the `tf.nn.rnn` call.